# Cache bits per row and total length

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, lru

If i have a

> 32bit address

,

> cache size(c) 8 KB

,

> Block Size(b) 16 B

,

> Set Associativity(a) 1

its a **Direct Mapped Cache**
what would be the bits per line in cache? including dirty bit and validity bit.
what would be the total no of lines in cache?

some idea which i got via searching on internet is

```
offset bits = log b = 4 bits
index bits = log c/b * 1024 = 9 bits
tag bits = 32 - offset - index = 19 bits
validity and dirty would have 1, 1 bit
```

still confused that how i will calculate size of cache or how many lines this cache would have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Internet search gave you the right answer.

- Block size of 16 bytes -> need 4 bits to specify the offset within the block.
- 8K byte cache and 16 byte lines -> 512 blocks. (8K / 16 = 512)
- Direct mapped cache -> 512 / 1 way set associativity = 512 sets
- 512 sets -> need 9 bits for the index (512 = 2^9)

With a 32 bit address, if 4 bits are used for the block offset and 9 for the index that means that the remaining 19 bits are needed for the tag.

Since this is a direct map cache, no bits are needed for a replacement policy (e.g. LRU).  You'll need at least one bit for validity.  With 2 bits you can implement a cache coherence algorithm like [MESI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol).  So figure 20 to 21 bits are needed per block.

Comment: bits per set would be (block size + tag + validity + dirty) (16*8=128 + 19 + 1 + 1) = 149 is that right? and 128/4 = 32bits per word coming from main memory?

Comment: Bits per set = (bits per block * blocks per set) + bits used for replacement policy.  For the OP's question that is (20 or 21 * 1) + 0.  Note that if a cache is write-through a dirty bit isn't needed.